# changing horizontal padding changes height of the super view SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI




public struct segmentedSlider<T, Content> : View where T: Hashable, Content: View {

    public let sources: [T]
    public let selection: T?
    private let itemBuilder: (T) -> Content
    private var customIndicator: AnyView? = nil
    
    public init(
    _ sources: [T],
    selection: T?,
    indicatorBuilder: @escaping () -> some View,
       @ViewBuilder itemBuilder: @escaping (T) -> Content
    ) {
       self.sources = sources
       self.selection = selection
       self.itemBuilder = itemBuilder
       self.customIndicator = AnyView(indicatorBuilder())
    }
    
    public init(
    _ sources: [T],
    selection: T?,
       @ViewBuilder itemBuilder: @escaping (T) -> Content
    ) {
       self.sources = sources
       self.selection = selection
       self.itemBuilder = itemBuilder
    }
    
    @State private var borderColor: Color?
    func borderColor(_ borderColor: Color) -> segmentedSlider {
    var view = self
       view._borderColor = State(initialValue: borderColor)
    return view
    }
    
    @State private var borderWidth: CGFloat?
    func borderWidth(_ borderWidth: CGFloat) -> segmentedSlider {
    var view = self
       view._borderWidth = State(initialValue: borderWidth)
    return view
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            
            if let selection = selection, let selectedIdx = sources.firstIndex(of: selection) {
            if let customIndicator = customIndicator {
                   customIndicator
               } else {
                   GeometryReader { geo in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.0)
                           .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                           .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 2, leading: 2, bottom: 2, trailing: 2))
                           .frame(width: geo.size.width / CGFloat(sources.count))
                           .animation(.spring().speed(1.5))
                           .offset(x: geo.size.width / CGFloat(sources.count) * CGFloat(selectedIdx), y: 0)
                   }
                   
               }
                // TODO: Add items
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(sources, id: \.self) { item in
                        itemBuilder(item)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        .scaledToFit()
        .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.0)
               .fill(
                Color.DesignSystem.white,
                strokeBorder: borderColor ?? Color.clear,
                lineWidth: borderWidth ?? .zero
               )
        )
    }
    
   
}

struct PreviewPickerPlus: View {
    @State private var selectedItem : String? = "Modes"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            segmentedSlider(
                           ["Modes","Wind Power", "Timer"],
            selection: selectedItem
                       ) { item in
            Text(item.capitalized)
                               .font(Font.footnote.weight(.medium))
                               .foregroundColor(selectedItem == item ? .white : .black)
                               .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                               .padding(.vertical, 0)
                               .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                               .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                               .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.150)) {
                                       selectedItem = item
                                   }
                               }
                               .overlay(
                                   RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                                       .stroke( Color.DesignSystem.blue, lineWidth: 1)
                                       .scaleEffect( 1.0)
                                       .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                               )
                       }
                       .borderColor(.blue)
                       .borderWidth(1)
                       .accentColor(.green)
                       .padding(0)
                       .background(.black)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct PickerPlus_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    
    static var previews: some View {
        PreviewPickerPlus()
    }
}

extension Shape {
    public func fill<Fill: ShapeStyle, Stroke: ShapeStyle>(_ fillStyle: Fill, strokeBorder strokeStyle: Stroke, lineWidth: Double = 0) -> some View {
        self
            .stroke(strokeStyle, lineWidth: lineWidth)
            .background(self.fill(fillStyle))
    }
}

extension InsettableShape {
    public func fill<Fill: ShapeStyle, Stroke: ShapeStyle>(_ fillStyle: Fill, strokeBorder strokeStyle: Stroke, lineWidth: Double = 0) -> some View {
        self
            .strokeBorder(strokeStyle, lineWidth: lineWidth)
            .background(self.fill(fillStyle))
    }
}
```

this is the code, right, when I pass Text view to my segmentedPicker class init ive tryed changing horizontal padding and the bigger padding becomes the smaller slider becomes (uploaded 2 images with 0 horizontal padding and 20)

[image][image]

just.. why?

why with 0 vertical padding and 0 horizontal it has some extra height but with extra horizontal padding height decreases

Comment: When you change the horizontal padding, which line of code did you change exactly?

Comment: @Sweeper PreviewPickerPlus body Vstack Text padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because a `GeometryReader` has a very small ideal height, which causes `scaledToFit` to work in an unexpected way.

- The green rounded rectangle contains a `GeometryReader`. A `GeometryReader` is greedy and tries to use all the space available, horizontally and vertically.
- The `ZStack` in the body of the `segmentedSlider` is being `scaledToFit`. This is bringing the height down to something more normal.
- If you take out the `.scaledToFit`, the green background fills the full height of the display.

The modifier `.scaledToFit` bases the scaling on the ideal sizes of the components. However, even though a `GeometryReader` will use all the space available, it's ideal size is actually very small. To confirm this, let's try a small test:

```swift
GeometryReader { proxy in
    Color.blue
        .onAppear {
            print("size=\(proxy.size.width)x\(proxy.size.height)")
        }
}
.fixedSize()
```

By applying `.fixedSize()`, the `GeometryReader` will only consume its ideal size, instead of being greedy. Here's what we see:

> size=10.0x10.0

Now lets put the `GeometryReader` inside a `ZStack` which also has another view that has a larger size. The modifier `.fixedSize()` is moved to the `ZStack`:

```swift
ZStack {
    Color.orange
        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)

    GeometryReader { proxy in
        Color.blue
            .onAppear {
                print("size=\(proxy.size.width)x\(proxy.size.height)")
            }
    }
}
.fixedSize()
```

In this case we see:

> size=25.0x25.0

The size of the `ZStack` is being determined by the size of its contents based on their ideal sizes. Once this size has been established and used for the layout, the `GeometryReader` expands to the full size of the `ZStack`.

Applying this to your selector, it will be the size of the `HStack` that will determine the size of the `ZStack` before scaling, which in turn will determine the size of the `GeometryReader`.

Let's see what space the `HStack` would need at its ideal size by commenting out the following:

- the `GeometryReader`
- the modifier `.scaledToFit()`
- in the `itemBuilder` closure, the foreground color for the item
- the `.frame` modifier that sets `maxWidth: .infinity` on an item
- the horizontal padding for the `RoundedRectangle` in the overlay
- the black background.

When the horizontal padding is at 20, this is what we get:

[image: Screenshot]

The size of the selector here is approx. 270x16

With horizontal padding of 0, it's like this:

[image: Screenshot]

The size of the selector here is approx. 150x16. The width has been reduced by 120pt, which is what we would expect, because padding of 2 x 20pt x 3 was taken away.

These screenshots were taken on an iPhone 15, which has a width of 393pt. When `scaledToFit` is applied, the constraining factor will be this width. The height of the scaled `GeometryReader` can therefore be calculated as follows:

- for horiontal padding of 20, scaled height = (393 / 270) * 16 = approx. 23pt
- for horizontal padding of 0, scaled height = (393 / 150) * 16 = approx. 42pt

**This explains the different sizes you were seeing.** If you measure the actual heights in the two cases, these calculated heights correspond very closely.

That leaves the question, why don't the text labels get scaled too? This is because, `scaledToFit` only changes the frame size and this only works on views that are resizable. In particular, it does not make the font size larger. So `scaledToFit` has no effect on the text labels being used here.

**How to avoid the sizing issue**

I would suggest you move the green rounded rectangle to the background of the `HStack` and use `.matchedGeometryEffect` to position it instead. This way, you don't need a `GeometryReader`, nor do you need `.scaledTofit`.

While we're at it, you might like to use a more-conventional capitalized name for the view and add a `value` parameter to the `.animation` modifier (the version without `value` is deprecated).

Like this:

```swift
public struct SegmentedSlider<T, Content> : View where T: Hashable, Content: View {

    @Namespace private var ns

    // other properties and functions as before

    public var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(sources, id: \.self) { item in
                itemBuilder(item)
                    .padding(.vertical, 6)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: item, in: ns, isSource: true)
            }
        }
        .background {
            if let selection = selection, let selectedIdx = sources.firstIndex(of: selection) {
                if let customIndicator = customIndicator {
                    customIndicator
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: selection, in: ns, isSource: false)
                } else {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.0)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                        .padding(2)
                        .animation(.spring().speed(1.5), value: selection)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: selection, in: ns, isSource: false)
                }
            }
        }
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.0)
                .fill(
                    Color.DesignSystem.white,
                    strokeBorder: borderColor ?? Color.clear,
                    lineWidth: borderWidth ?? .zero
                )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I am generally impressed by the work done in this answer putting everything in, structure etc. Many thanks! I have to test it to ensure and then I will mark it as an answer, but I already can say you are a great guy!